# In Diablo III, does gold find effect the amount of gold received from chests?

Tags: diablo-iii

As the title stated, does gold find affect the amount of gold received from chests?

Answer (score 15):

I conducted some tests using the treasure chest by the waypoint in Cathedral garden. I ran 70 trials. 35 with 31% Gold Find, and 35 with no Gold Find. To sum up the data(which is below), **the difference between the gold gotten from the chest with 31% Gold Find and the gold gotten with no Gold Find is 32.99%**. So yes, Gold Find does have an effect on the amount of gold from chests, and furthermore, the increase is the same percentage(on average) as the listed Gold Find on your character sheet.

```
    No Gold Find     31% Gold Find
      298              199
       49               75 
      189              130
       11              143
      203                0
       44              332
       45              141
       35              360
        0               53
        0                9
      263               89
      281              141
        0              183
       93              133
       66              280
       62              223
       41               57
      399              115 
       43                6
       60              143
      561              103
      274              157
       10                0
      125              145
      100               47
       15               34
       76              467             
       40              312
       49              121
       46                0
       56              514
       83               24
       51               49
       82               70
      121              293
Sum: 3871             5148 
Avg: 110.6            147.09
```

Answer (score 1):

Magic Find and Gold Find seem to work the same way, and since Magic Find affects loot quality in chests, I would assume Gold Find does too

This would probably be easy to test by opening a bunch of treasure chests without gold find, taking note of the average, then realoading the game and opening chests in the same area with gold find. You should see a noticeable increase in gold found.

Comment: Do you have a source for MF working on chests? I could not find one :(

Comment: @Wikwocket Arreat Summit confirms that it worked on chests in D2, so absent proof otherwise, I would guess that still holds.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find an official source on this, but I believe it does affect chests. Here are some unofficial sources:

- http://www.diablowiki.net/Magic_find: "Magic Find increases the odds for found items (from monsters **or objects**) to be 'higher quality'."
- http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5151719222
- http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/930659-/62867379